# Pass, edit and return variable in C

Tags: c, function

I want to pass an integer to a function, have the function edit it and then pass back the integer to the main function. I am working on this but it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
int update_SEG_values(int DIGIT_1, int DIGIT_2) {

    // How many tens in the "TEMP_COUNT".
    DIGIT_2 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 10);

    // How much is left for us to display.
    TEMP_COUNT = TEMP_COUNT - ((DIGIT_2) * 10);

    // How many ones.
    DIGIT_1 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 1);

    return(DIGIT_1, DIGIT_2);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you defined TEMP_COUNT somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only return one value in C

when you give :

```
return(DIGIT_1, DIGIT_2);
```

due to the comma operator `DIGIT_2` will be returned. For more info refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

You can get your job done by using pointers or structures (both digits will be part of same structure and you return the same)

Comment: Or you could pass back an array instead of pointers of structs.

Answer (score 1):

C does not let you return multiple values. If you need to change a value passed into the function, you need to pass it by pointer:

```
void update_SEG_values(int *DIGIT_1, int *DIGIT_2) // Note the void
```

Inside the function, dereference the pointer to change the value:

```
*DIGIT_2 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 10); // Note the asterisk
...
*DIGIT_1 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 1);
```

When calling the function, you need to pass pointers to variables, like this:

```
int digit1 = 5, digit2 = 1;
update_SEG_values(&digit1, &digit2); // Note the ampersands
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return two values at one time. Consider using pointers so that the values themselves will be modified without returning anything.

```
// note the change to "void" in the function's signature--it will not return anything,
// rather, it will change the information passed in through the pointer parameters
void update_SEG_values(int *DIGIT_1, int *DIGIT_2)
{
    // How many tens in the "TEMP_COUNT".
    *DIGIT_2 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 10);

    // How much is left for us to display.
    TEMP_COUNT = TEMP_COUNT - ((DIGIT_2) * 10);

    // How many ones.
    *DIGIT_1 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 1);
    // The variables passed in as params for DIGIT_1 and _2 will be updated
    // in the main function w/o needing to return anything
}
```

[More info on pointers](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the address of the variables to the function. If any changes done, then it will be reflected.

```
update_SEG_values(int *DIGIT_1, int *DIGIT_2)
{

...
}
```

call the function with the address of the int values like,

```
int a, b;
update_SEG_values(&a, &b);
```

Returning two integers does not serve your purpose.

Look at modified code. I guess you take care of TEMP_COUNT.

```
void update_SEG_values(int *DIGIT_1, int *DIGIT_2) {

    /* How many tens in the "TEMP_COUNT". */
    *DIGIT_2 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 10);

    /* How much is left for us to display. */
    TEMP_COUNT = TEMP_COUNT - ((*DIGIT_2) * 10);

    /* How many ones. */
    *DIGIT_1 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 1);

    return; //No use anyway. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.  You can either pass the integers by reference and have no return value, or you can create a struct for the tuple you are trying to return.

The first way looks like:

```
void update_SEG_values(int* DIGIT_1, int* DIGIT_2) {

    /* How many tens in the "TEMP_COUNT". */
    *DIGIT_2 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 10);

    /* How much is left for us to display. */
    TEMP_COUNT = TEMP_COUNT - ((*DIGIT_2) * 10);

    /* How many ones. */
    *DIGIT_1 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 1);
}

int main() {
    int x = 111, y = 222;
    int result = update_SEG_values(&x, &y);
    ....

}
```

The second way looks like:

```
struct tuple {
    int DIGIT_1;
    int DIGIT_2;
};

struct tuple update_SEG_values(int DIGIT_1, int DIGIT_2) {

    /* How many tens in the "TEMP_COUNT". */
    DIGIT_2 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 10);

    /* How much is left for us to display. */
    TEMP_COUNT = TEMP_COUNT - ((DIGIT_2) * 10);

    /* How many ones. */
    DIGIT_1 = ((TEMP_COUNT) / 1);

    struct tuple result;
    result.DIGIT_1 = DIGIT_1;
    result.DIGIT_2 = DIGIT_2;
    return result;
}
```

I also notice you don't have TEMP_COUNT defined anywhere.  It should be initialized before using it in update_SEG_values, probably as the first line of that function.